# Unlogical Access Points Appearing in NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-security

I'm just trying to confirm my suspicions, I live in a rural area, with only 1 neighbor close enough for me to catch their wifi signal. Last night I noticed a new essid, telus_smart_hub, which when connected to, threw an error,

(7) The access point /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/24 was not in the scan list.
 **( pulled off internet to replicate )**

The telus AP was still going for most of the day, and then it eventually turned into NETGEAR, with the same error

Neighbors normal AP remained up through all of this, your thought's are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you google "telus smart hub", you will see that it is a router that connects to 4g and gives wifi on a data plan. This means that your neighbors could have recently purchased it. You should ask them about it.